# Trace function equation

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_{2^{m}}$ (a field of characteristic $2$, m odd), with $a,b\neq 0$.
I need to prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{(m-1)/2}\operatorname{tr}(a^{2^{i}}b+b^{2^{i}}a)=0\qquad \text{ iff }\qquad a=b,$$

where $\operatorname{tr}:\mathbb{F}_{2^{m}}\longrightarrow\mathbb{F}_2$ is the trace function.

Comment: The claim is wrong as stated. If either $a=04 or $b=0$, the sum obviously vanishes. What exactly did you want to ask?

Comment: Sorry Dimitri, I acted too quickly. I've undone my actions.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen sorry i forget to say $a,b\neq 0$, i have edited the question, thanks for let me now the error

Comment: @Zev (and Dimitri): I apologize, the questions are different even though the questions and answers could be merged. The morning **is** wiser :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the form takes values in the prime field it is nigh impossible for it to vanish **only** when $a=b$. Indeed, for a given $a$ it vanishes for at least half of the possible values of $b$ (if not all) by bilinearity alone. Hence I assume that the question is really to prove that the
bilinear form vanishes whenever $a=b$.

I give two proofs. The latter is more trivial, but the former is suggested by
[my answer to another question about this form](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/313423/11619). There I derive the formula
$$
B(a,b)=tr(ab)+tr(a)tr(b).
$$
Using the fact $tr(a)=tr(a^2)$ (the Frobenius conjugates have the same trace) we can deduce the present claim easily.
If $a=b$ we have
$$
B(a,a)=tr(a^2)+tr(a)^2=tr(a)+tr(a)^2.
$$
As $tr(a)$ is either $0$ or $1$ this is equal to zero.

---

Oh dear, I'm sluggish. Here is a straightforward proof:

If $a=b$, then $a^{2^i}b+ab^{2^i}=a^{1+2^i}+a^{1+2^i}=0$ for all $a$ and all $i$.
The claim follows immediately from this.

Comment: So I guess an explicit counterexample would be if $b=1$ then it collapses to $(m-1)tr(a)=0$?

Comment: @JSchlather, $m = 3$, and $\Bbb{F}_{8}$ given as $\Bbb{F}_{2}(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $f = x^{3} + x + 1$. Take $a = \alpha, b = 1$. Then the value of the expression is $\operatorname{tr}(\alpha^{2} + \alpha) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, @JSchlather. Your example is a good one. The answer to the linked question proves that $b=1$ is the only non-zero element that is "orthogonal" to all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas (too long for a comment):

1) $\,tr(x+y)=tr(x)+tr(y)\,$ ;

2) By [Hilbert's Theorem 90 (additive form)](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CD0QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fnptel.iitm.ac.in%2Fcourses%2F111101001%2Fdownloads%2FLecture25.pdf&ei=pJ0qUcGsCsfe4QSZmIDwCg&usg=AFQjCNGTQ3jOAo_2EM0V8ghn8uglK7Pb-Q&sig2=GsiLSGzbQ-HLK_jjG0aUFg) (page 4) , we get that

$$tr(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow x=\alpha-\alpha^2\;\;,\;\;\alpha\in\Bbb F_{2^{m-1}}$$

3) [Every element in $\,\Bbb F_{2^{m-1}}\,$ is a square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30354/finite-field-every-element-is-a-square-implies-char-equal-2)