# Why can a quadratic equation have only 2 roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

It is commonly known that the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two solutions given by: $$x = \frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ But how do I prove that another root couldn't exist?

I think derivation of quadratic formula is not enough....

Comment: No, it's not "commonly known", because it's not always true: it's only true if $b^2 > 4ac$ (given the tag, I'm assuming we're working in $\mathbb{R}$). The derivation of the quadratic formula is enough, because the derivation characterizes all solutions to the equation. Alternatively, you could note that the derivative has exactly one zero and thus by Rolle's theorem the polynomial has at most $2$ roots.

Comment: It's referred to as "The fundamental theorem of algebra" that counting multiple roots and complex roots, polynomials of degree n have n roots.  You can google it.

Comment: "given the tag, I'm assuming we're working in R"  and "Alternatively, you could note that the derivative has exactly one zero and thus by Rolle's theorem"..... Um...?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots

Comment: @fleablood Don't understand your comment.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 - pre-calculus students who have reached the point of quadratic equations and have heard that quadratics have two roots have likely encountered complex numbers. However, since they are *pre*-calculus, they are highly unlikely to be familiar with derivatives and Rolle's theorem.

Comment: @AtulMishra - Actually, derivation of the quadratic formula is enough: That derivation starts with an arbitrary solution to the polynomial, and shows that it has one of those two values. Therefore those two values are the only ones possible.

Comment: Can you assume that all polynomials can be written in the form $c(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\ldots$? Or do you need a proof of that too? Because if you can assume that, then the answer is trivially easy (just observer that having more than 2 roots implies a degree for $x$ greater than 2.)

Comment: This is a nice question +1

Comment: If $a=b=c=0$, then the "quadratic" equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has many, many, many solutions....

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 you are so wrong. It is commonly known, and it is always true.

Comment: When $b^2=4ac$ there is only one root, repeated twice. Further when working in $\mathbb{R}$ it's not true for $b^2<4ac$ either, when there are zero roots. Something that is not possible to know cannot be commonly known.

Comment: The clue to the 2 root question is that it is a 2nd degree equation. Ax^2+Bx+c - anything squared can have two roots - the positive and the negative.

Comment: Similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25822/how-to-prove-that-a-polynomial-of-degree-n-has-at-most-n-roots

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Suppose there are three distinct roots $x,y,z$. One has
$$\begin{cases}ax^2+bx+c=0\\ay^2+by+c=0\\az^2+bz+c=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}a(x^2-y^2)+b(x-y)=0\\a(x^2-z^2)+b(x-z)=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}a(x+y)+b=0\\a(x+z)+b=0\end{cases}$$ It follows $$a(z-y)=0\Rightarrow z=y$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: your last system should be $a(x+y)+b = 0$ and $a(x+z)+b=0$.  The rest stand, great proof.

Comment: I often mistaken for hurry (many times, because of my bad English, when I have finished my writing  an equal answer has already been published.) Thank you.

Comment: I can't see how you get from the second system to the third system.

Comment: @Wildcard Expand $(x^2 - y^2)$ as $(x + y)(x - y)$, then cancel factors of $x - y$. Do the same for $(x^2 - z^2)$.

Comment: @TannerSwett, ah, so he's dividing by $(x-y)$ and by $(x-z)$.  Well, at least that explains how he specifically derived that $z \ne y$ with nothing about $x$.  (There's nothing special to distinguish $x$ from $y$ from $z$ in the original system.)

Comment: @Wildcard Right. And it's also implicit that it's ok to divide by these terms because by the assumption of distinct roots neither of these can be zero.

Comment: @Wildcard there is a hidden problem there. You can not divide by zero. So he should state two options before, that x-y=0 or x-z=0 or if neither then and only then one can proceed with the said divisions.

Comment: That said, the answer still lacks proof that a-b=0 implies a=b :)

Comment: It would be great if we had an $a \ne 0$ in there.

Comment: @HughMeyers But it's not always ok to cancel those factots, e.g. it doesn't  work when the coefficients are integers mod $m,\,$ e.g. $\,x^2- 1\,$ has *four* roots $\, x\equiv 1,3,5,7\,$ modulo $8$. See my answer and its links for more on the general case.

Comment: @Arioch'The, see the first sentence of the answer.  Ensure you understand the word "distinct."  Then see if your comment still makes sense.  :)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins - Recall the phrase "quadratic equation" in the title of the OP's posting. If $a=0$, one doesn't have a quadratic equation to start with. Thus, the condition $a\ne0$ is true automatically as long as one is working with (non-trivial!!) quadratic equations.

Comment: @Wildcard well, in a hindsight this whole question makes little sense. Frankly, it sounds like "why are you so sure a combustion engine fuel is flammable? Prove it!" Still if we set to prove it we should assume the recipient is very inexperienced and detailed comments are needed.

Comment: Perhaps you should mention that the second implication rely on $x\ne y$ and $x\ne z$? Also the last implication relies on $a\ne 0$ (actually if $a=b=c=0$ the equation has infinite number of roots).

Comment: @Piquito: I think the contradiction should be $a=0,$ and hence $b=c=0.$ In fact, this zero quadratic has more than two zeros (depending on the domain of definition).

Comment: This proof is wonderful in its simplicity.

Answer (score 56):

> I think derivation of quadratic formula is not enough....

Yes it is. The derivation is of the form **if** $ax^2+bx+c=0$, **then** $x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. The derivation is a proof if you pay attention.

The trickiest step is simply that if $y^2 = k$ for $k \geq 0$ then $y = \pm \sqrt k$, if you do not take this as evident.

Comment: All that needed to be said.

Comment: @JackM thanks. I do think the answers regarding polynomial factorization over fields/integral domains, and how this relates to the fundamental theorem of algebra, are pretty useful.

Answer (score 28):

$$0 = ax^2 + bx + c$$

We solve this equation by completing the square. It offers up to two distinct solutions. The *name* we give to the general solutions is the quadratic formula. That's all there is.

If we consider the case of real solutions, and you think there may be a sneaky third solution, remember that $f(x) = ax^2 +bx +c$ can be plotted as below (depending on the sign of $a$). How many times could a parabola cross a horizontal line?

[image: parabola intersecting various horizontal lines]

Comment: this is but a specific degenerate case of 2D plane! Generalize it at very least to 3D complex space and you would easily see there are much more solutions !!! :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The um, precalculus...

Comment: You seem to be presuming that we are working over the field of real numbers, but the question makes no such restriction. And even over the reals that is not a rigorous proof.

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, that is all true. What's also true is that Math.SE exists for users of all levels. It's beneficial to provide responses that could meet varying expectations, unless the problem specifies.

Comment: This feels circular to me, don't you need to prove that _all_ quadratics have a graph like that?

Comment: Useful <> Rigorous, it is possible for ideas that lack rigor to be useful, and moreover, useful to mathematical understanding. The point is, is it likely to be an accurate model? If so, its' potentially useful as an aid to understanding, regardless of whether or not we have a proof of its accuracy

Comment: @RemcoGerlich standupmaths made a "[There is only One True Parabola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w)" video demonstrating all parabolas are similar.

Comment: Upvote.  That graphic is great.  The clue to the 2 root question is that it is a 2nd degree equation.  Ax^2+Bx+c  - anything squared can have two roots - the positive and the negative.  Since this is the kind of equations used in GPS the navigation systems usually come up with 2 answers and the system is smart enough to pick the one that is on the surface of the earth.

Answer (score 22):

A more general answer to this question lies in the following theorem:

**Theorem** If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, and $a$ is a value for which $P(a) = 0$, then $P(x) = (x - a)Q(x)$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n - 1$.

This theorem is a simple consequence of polynomial long division. By long division, $P(x) = (x - a)Q(x) + R(x)$, for some polynomials $Q(x), R(x)$ with the degree of $R(x)$ less than the degree of $(x-a)$. But since $x - a$ is of degree 1, that means $R(x)$ is of degree $0$. I.e., $R(x) = R$, a constant.

But $P(a) = 0$, so $0 = (a - a)Q(a) + R$, and so $R = 0$ and we get just $P(x) = (x-a)Q(x)$. Since the degree of the product of two polynomials is the sum of their degrees, the degree of $P(x)$ is one greater than that of $Q(x)$, so the degree of $Q(x)$ must be $n-1$.

---

Now, if $P_n(x)$ is of degree $n > 0$ and $a_n$ is a root, then $$P_n(x) = (x - a_n)P_{n-1}(x)$$ for some $n-1$ degree polynomial $P_{n-1}(x)$. If $P_n(x)$ has another root $a \ne a_n$, then $a$ must also be a root of $P_{n-1}(x)$:

$$0 = P_n(a) = (a - a_n)P_{n-1}(a)$$
Since $a - a_n \ne 0$, we can divide it out to get $P_{n-1}(a) = 0$.

Conversely, if $a_{n-1}$ is a root of $P_{n-1}$, then $$P_n(a_{n-1}) = (a_{n-1} - a_n)P_{n-1}(a_{n-1}) = 0$$
So $a_{n-1}$ must also be a root of $P_n$ (which may be the same or different from $a_n$). We can also apply the theorem to $P_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-1}$:
$$P_{n-1}(x) = (x - a_{n-1})P_{n-2}(x)$$
for some degree $n-2$ polynomial $P_{n-2}(x)$. By combining, we see that $$P_n(x) = (x - a_n)(x - a_{n-1})P_{n-2}(x)$$
As long as we can keep finding roots for the reduced polynomials, we can keep this up. If we can find $k$ such roots,
$$P_n(x) = (x - a_n)(x - a_{n-1})(x - a_{n-2})...(x - a_{n+1-k})P_{n-k}(x)$$
Then $P_{n-k}(x)$ has to be a polynomial of degree $n-k$.

If we can find $n$ such roots, then 
$$P_n(x) = (x-a_n)(x-a_{n-1})...(x-a_1)P_0$$
where $P_0$ is a constant (a $0$-degree polynomial). $P_0 \ne 0$, since if it were we would have $P_n(x) = 0$ everywhere. But then the degree of $P_n$ would be $0$ (or less - some people define the degree of the $0$ to be $-\infty$), contrary to our original condition on $P_n(x)$. So in this case, $P_n(x)$ cannot have any other roots distinct from $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$, since any other value would leave all factors in the expression non-zero.

So $P_n(x)$ can have at most $n$ roots.

The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that any non-constant polynomial over the complex numbers has a root. This theorem requires a substantial development of the properties of complex numbers to prove. But by it, we see that the process above does not terminate until you get to the constant. Thus a polynomial of degree $n$ will always have exactly $n$ roots $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. But remember that the $a_i$ values do not have to be distinct. The number of times a particular value occurs in this list is called the multiplicity of the root. So you only get $n$ if you count the roots by their multiplicity.

Answer (score 21):

**Hint** $ $ If $f(x)\,$ is a polynomial of $\color{#0a0}{{\rm degree}\,2}\,$ with coef's in a $\rm\color{#c00}{field}$ (or $\rm\color{#c00}{domain}$) $F$ (e.g. $\,\Bbb Q,\Bbb R,\Bbb C,\Bbb Z_p)$ and $\,f\,$ has $\,2\,$ distinct roots $\,a\neq b,\,$ then applying the Bifactor Theorem below we deduce that $\,f(x) = c(x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)\,$ for $\,\color{#0a0}{0\neq c}\in F.\,$ Thus if $\,d\neq a,b\,$ then $\,f(d) = c(d\!-\!a)(d\!-\!b)\ne 0\,$ since each factor is $\ne 0\,$ (recall $\,x,y\ne 0\,\Rightarrow\,xy\ne 0\,$ in a $\rm\color{#c00}{field}$). Thus a $\rm\color{#0a0}{quadratic}$ has at most $\,\color{#0a0}2\,$  roots.

**Bifactor Theorem** $\ $ Suppose that $\rm\,a,b\,$ are elements of a field $\rm\,F\,$ and $\rm\:f\in F[x],\,$ i.e. $\rm\,f\,$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $\rm\,F.\,$ If $\rm\ \color{#C00}{a\ne b}\ $ are elements of $\rm\,F\,$ then

$$\rm f(a) = 0 = f(b)\ \iff\ f\, =\, (x\!-\!a)(x\!-\!b)\ h\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in F[x]$$

**Proof** $\,\ (\Leftarrow)\,$ clear. $\ (\Rightarrow)\ $ Applying  [Factor Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) twice, while canceling $\rm\: \color{#C00}{a\!-\!b\ne 0},$

$$\begin{eqnarray}\rm\:f(b)= 0 &\ \Rightarrow\ &\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ g\in F[x]\\
\rm f(a) = (\color{#C00}{a\!-\!b})\,g(a) = 0 &\Rightarrow&\rm g(a)\, =\, 0\,\ \Rightarrow\ g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\ \ for\ \ some\ \ h\in F[x]\\
&\Rightarrow&\rm f(x)\, =\, (x\!-\!b)\,g(x) \,=\, (x\!-\!b)(x\!-\!a)\,h(x)\end{eqnarray}$$

**Remark**  $ $ More generally, by inductively iterating the Factor Theorem (as we did above) we deduce that a nonzero polynomial $\,f\,$ over a field (or domain) has no more roots than its degree $\,n.\,$  Indeed if $\,f\,$ has  $\,\ge n\,$ distinct roots $\,r_i$ then inductively applying the  Factor Theorem shows that $\,f = c(x\!-\!r_1)\cdots (x\!-\!r_n),\,$ so $\ r\ne r_i\Rightarrow\, f(r)= c(r\!-\!r_1)\cdots (r\!-\!r_n) \ne 0\,$ by all factors are $\ne 0.\,$ Thus $\,f\,$ has at most $\,n\,$ roots.

The above root-bound property characterizes (integral) domains (commutative rings $\ne \{0\}$ which satisfy $\rm\,ab=0\,\Rightarrow\, a=0\,$ or $\rm\,b=0),\,$  viz. a ring $\rm\: D\:$ is a domain $\iff$ every nonzero polynomial $\rm\ f(x)\in D[x]\ $ has at most $\rm\ deg\ f\ $ roots in $\rm\:D.\:$ For a simple proof see  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/simple-explanation-and-examples-of-the-miller-rabin-primality-test/4604#4604), where I illustrate it constructively in $\rm\: \mathbb Z/m\: $ by showing that, given any $\rm\:f(x)\:$ with more roots than its degree, we can quickly compute a nontrivial factor of $\rm\:m\:$ via a quick $\rm\:gcd.\,$

The quadratic case of this result is at the heart of some integer factorization algorithms, which e.g. attempt to factor $\rm\:m\:$ by searching for a square-root of $1$ that is nontrivial $(\not\equiv \pm1)$ in $\rm\: \mathbb Z/m.$

**Beware** that there are very simple examples of failure in non-domains, e.g. if $\,ab=0, a,b\neq 0\,$ then $\,ax\,$ has at least $2$ roots $\,b,0,\,$ and $\,(x-a)(x-b)\,$ has at least $\,4\,$ roots $\,a,b,0,a+b\, $ if $\,a\neq  b.\,$ A simple concrete case is in $\,\Bbb Z_8 = $ integers $\!\bmod 8\!:\,$ $\rm{odd}^2= 1\,$ so $\,x^2-1\,$ has $\,4\,$ roots $\,\pm1,\pm 3.$

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/868550/242) for a generalization from domains to any commutative ring.

Answer (score 13):

Suppose it has three roots and $a\neq0$.

The hypotheses of Rolles Theorem are satisfied then there will exist two roots of the derivative and a root of the second derivative which is a constant $(=2a)$.

Answer (score 13):

Let
$$r=\frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a},\quad s=\frac{-b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
Simple calculation shows that
$$r+s=-\frac ba\quad\text{ and }\quad rs=\frac{b^2-(b^2-4ac)}{4a^2}=\frac ca.$$
Thus
$$a(x-r)(x-s)=a[x^2-(r+s)x+rs]=ax^2+bx+c.$$
If $t$ is any root of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0,$ then
$$a(t-r)(t-s)=at^2+bt+c=0.$$
Since $a\ne0$ this means that
$$(t-r)(t-s)=0$$
whence
$$t-r=0\quad\text{ or }\quad t-s=0,$$
i.e.,
$$t=r\quad\text{ or }\quad t=s.$$

Answer (score 6):

I think I can simplify the 'polynomial long division' answer.  The special case of polynomial long division says that, for *any* polynomial $P$, and *any* real number $a$,
$$P(x) = Q(x)(x-a) + R$$
for some polynomial $Q$ and *constant* $R$ (use long division to divide $P$ by $x-a$ and observer that $R$ is required to be a constant since it must have lower degree than $x-a$, which is a first-degree polynomial).

The above is true for *all* $x$, so substituting $x=a$ we get
$$P(a) = Q(a)(a-a) + R$$
Obviously, $a-a=0$, so $R=P(a)$.

If $a$ is a 0 of $P$ ($P(a)=0$), then $R=0$, so $x-a$ divides $P(x)$.

Now, if we have any distinct root $a$ of a quadratic polynomial $P$, we know
$$P(x) = Q(x)(x-a)$$
$Q$ must be a first-degree polynomial, since anything higher-degree, multiplied by a first-degree polynomial, would produce a higher-than-second-degree polynomial.  So
$$P(x) = (x-b)(x-a)$$
Now, assuming we're working over an integral domain (which $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ both are),
$$P(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x-b=0 \text{ or } x-a=0$$
So $a$ and $b$ are the only zeros of $P$ (although it is possible that $a=b$).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose not. Then there are at least 3 roots and so $$P(x)=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)Q(x)$$ This is at least a cubic so this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the theorem out, it would look like this

**THEOREM**: Let $a,b,$ and $c$ be real numbers with $a \ne 0$. Then $ax^2+bx+c=0$ **if and only if** $x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$.

That means

**if** $ax^2+bx+c=0$, **then** $x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$

**and**

**if** $x = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$, **then** $ax^2+bx+c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $a \neq 0$. Then $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has the same set of solutions as $x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{c}{a}=0$ which means that we can reduce all equations to

$$x^2+px+q=0$$

without losing generality.

Suppose $q=0$, then it is $x^2+px=0$ when either $x=0$ or $x+p=0$, but $x+p=0$ has only one solution by definition $x=-p$

Next, take then $q \neq 0$, when

$$x(x+p)=-q$$

Take $y=x+\frac{p}{2}$ which makes

$$(y+\frac{p}{2})(y-\frac{p}{2})=y^2-\frac{p^2}{4}=-q$$

or

$$y^2=-q+\frac{p^2}{4}=b$$

So it comes down to a question of how many different roots square root may have.

Write two of them which we suspect:

$$y_1^2=b$$

$$y_2^2=b$$

$$y_1^2-y_2^2=(y_1-y_2)(y_1+y_2)=0$$

So it is either $y_1=y_2$ which gives the same solution or $y_1=-y_2$ which connects the solutions in such a way that there cannot be two different negative values of the same number. Since the connections of reduced solution $y_1,y_2$ are connected with $y_1=-y_2$ the starting set of solutions must have the same cardinality: no more than $2$.

Finally if $a=0$ there can be only one solution by definition.