# How can you say it is true or false?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

[image]

Can we compare an equation like I did. Given that $p(x)$ has real roots. If it true, Would it also be true when roots are imaginary?
Is it true. Please help

Comment: Try what you did explicitly with any quadratic with $a \geq 2$.

Comment: Yes I do not get them equal but how to prove ot wrong? I mean what arguement can we give?

Comment: See the [Bifactor Theorem.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for a careful proof of the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite right. Saying $p(x)$ has two roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does not mean that $p(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$. You are forgetting that any constant times $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ will still have roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$. So, what you can conclude is that
$$
p(x)=c(x-\alpha)(x-\beta),
$$
where $c$ is a constant. From the expansion, it follows, in fact, that $c=a$.

Answer (score 0):

If a polynomial $p$ of degree $2$ has the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then

$$p(x)=a(x- \alpha)(x - \beta)$$

Answer (score 0):

The comparison you did is true, **but...**

In your case the fact that $a=1$ is wrong, since there are possibilities that the $\alpha$ or $\beta$ may be in fraction.

Comment: I agree with you. +1

Comment: @John Thanks to you

Comment: @HarshKumar Thats good. +1

Answer (score 0):

Nothing allows you to say that I and II are identical, and they aren't !

All you know is that they have the same roots, i.e. that they cancel at $x=\alpha$ and $x=\beta$, meaning that

$$a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c=a\beta^2+b\beta+c=0,$$

which can be written

$$a(\alpha^2-\beta^2)+b(\alpha-\beta)=0$$

and even

$$a(\alpha+\beta)+b=0$$ if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known to be different.

There is nothing more that you can conclude.