# Doesn't this famous theorem work also in domains?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, proof-verification, ring-theory, integral-domain

If $R$ is a (commutative) ring, we have for $f(x), g(x) \in R[x]$ and $b_m$ the leading coefficient of $g$ that there is $t \in \mathbb N$ and $q(x),r(x) \in R[x]$ such that $$b_m^t f(x) = q(x) g(x) + r(x)$$

This can be seen by induction on $\deg f$ and writing:

$$f_1(x) = b_m f(x) - a_n x^{n-m} g(x)$$

when $\deg f \ge m=\deg g$.

A corollary of this is:

> If $R$ is a (commutative) ring and $f(x) \in R[x]$ and $a \in R$, then there exists $q(x)$ such that
>
> $$f(x) = (x-a)q(x) + f(a)$$

by taking $g(x) = x - a$.

A corollary to this corollary is:

> If $R$ is a ring and $f(x) \in R[x]$ and $a \in R$, then $(x-a) \mid f(x)$ iff $f(a) = 0$.

Now **my question** is: doesn't this have the following corollary?

> If $D$ is a domain and $f(x) \in D[x]$ has degree $n$, then $f(x)$ has at most $n$ roots in $D$.

Suggested proof:

We prove by induction on $t$ that if $a_1,\ldots,a_t$ are distinct roots of $f(x)$, then $f(x)$ is divisible by $(x-a_1)(\cdots)(x-a_t)$. For $t=1$ this follows by the above corollary. Suppose now $a_1,\ldots,a_t$ are roots. By induction hypothesis, $f(x) = g(x) \prod_{i=1}^{t-1} (x-a_i)$.

Now $0= f(a_t) = g(a_t)(a_t - a_1)(\cdots)(a_t - a_{t-1})$. Since $D$ is a domain and each $a_t - a_i \neq 0$, we get $g(a_t) = 0$ and so $x-a_t$ divides $g(x)$. So $f(x) = h(x) \prod (x - a_i)$. So we are done.

But this shows any such $t$ is $\le n$. So this completes the proof.

Comment: See no problems. The corollary is fine.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your proof because polynomials over the quaternions (a "non-commutative" field) can have more roots than their degrees.

Comment: I think the problem is your proof is implicitly assuming unique factorization, which does not hold in the general polynomial ring.

Comment: @GregoryGrant: I don't think so. The induction hypothesis  explicitly specifies divisibility by the product of the linear factors.

Comment: Oh, if it's commutative then the proof is even easier, just replace $D$ by its field of fractions.  It has at most $n$ roots there so it has at most $n$ roots in $D$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant sorry for not making it clear. Everything is assumed commutative. I stated it between parentheses twice then stopped stating it hoping this will make the reader implicitly assume commutativity.

Comment: Yes, these are all well-known results discussed in many other answers, e.g. the [nommonic polynomial division algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242), and the bifactor  / n-factor theorem and characterization of domains as commutative rings where polys have no more than degree roots are in [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242)