# Incorrect proof of Wilson's Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

While looking for alternative proofs for the theorem, I came across the following [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Wilson%27s_Theorem)

**The proof**

Let $p$ be a prime number. By Fermat's little theorem, all non-zero elements of the field must be the roots of the polynomial $P(x)=x^{p-1}-1$.

$x^{p-1}-1= \prod_{r = 1}^{p-1}(x-r)$

Now, either $p=2$, in which case $a \equiv -a \pmod 2$ for any integer $a$, or $p-1$ is even. In either case, $(-1)^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, so that

$x^{p-1}-1=\prod_{ r=1}^{p-1}(x-r)=\prod(r-x)$

If we set $x=0$ then we get the theorem.

My question is, if we have assumed that $x$ is non-zero in the beginning, how can we substitute it back in the end to get the theorem?

Can someone verify if this proof is correct or not and, if it is, explain why doing this is allowed?

Comment: You've proved that the polynomial $P(x)$ has the $p-1$ roots modulo $p,$ so that $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots(x-(p-1))$ modulo $p.$ This equality is an equality of polynomials, not just functions on $1,2,\dots,p-1$, so it has to be true for $x=0$ too.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between polynomial *functions* and *formal* polynomials, e.g.  over $\,\Bbb F_p,\,$ by $\,\mu$Fermat, $\, x^p -x \,$ equals the constant *function* $\,0,\,$ but it is not equal to $\,0\,$ as a *formal* polynomial since, by definition, formal polyomials are equal iff their corresponding coefficients are equal.

Comment: @BillDubuque I did not know the difference. Thanks. So basically, $P(x) = (x−1)(x−2)(x−3)⋯(x−(p−1)) \forall x \in  \mathbb{F}_p$ since degree of $P$ = number of roots in $ \mathbb{F}_p$. Meaning that at least in $\mathbb{F}_p$, they are equal.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Have you yet studied [fields?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))

Comment: @BillDubuque No. I've studied group theory but not fields. Was my comment incorrect?

Comment: Be more precise and complete about which set of values of x is the set applicable to  a given sentence, and incorporate that information right into the sentence.......You may have seen the following way to prove Wilson's Theorem: Multiplication modulo the prime $p,$ on the set $\{1,...,p-1\}$ is a commutative group. What do you get when you take the product of all the members of a finite commutative group?

Answer (score 1):

It is a special case of the following

**Theorem** $ $ Suppose  $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials of degree $n$ whose coefficients lie in a field $F$ (e.g. $\Bbb Q,\, \Bbb R$ or $\Bbb Z_p =$ integers $\bmod p$). If $f$ and $g$ have equal degree $n$ and equal lead coefs and they have equal values at $n$ distinct points $\in F$ then they have equal corresponding coefs $\,f_i = g_i\,$ for all $\,i\,$ (i.e. $f = g$ as *formal* polynomials), therefore $f$ and $g$ have equal values at *all* points $\in F$.

**Proof** $\ $ By hypothesis $f$ and $g$ have equal lead terms which cancel in $\,h := f-g\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{\deg h < n}.\, $ Thus $\,h\,$ is zero at the  $\color{#c00}{n > \deg h}\,$ distinct points where $f$ and $g$ have equal values. By a [well-known theorem,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) if a polynomial over a field has $\rm\color{#c00}{more\ roots}$ than its degree then it is the zero polynomial, i.e. all its coefs are zero, so $\, h_i = f_i - g_i = 0$.