# All coefficients of $P(x)$ are divisible by $7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

> Let $P(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $\deg (P(x)) = 4$. Suppose for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$,  $7 \mid  P(t)$. Show that all coefficients of $P(x)$ are divisible by $7$.

Should we use the Eisenstein criterion in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $ $ If $\,7\nmid f(x)\,$ then $\bmod 7\!:\ 0\not\equiv f$ has more 
roots than its degree: $\,x\equiv 0,1,2,\ldots, 6$

Comment: [Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) that over a field (or domain) a nonzero polynomial has no more roots than its degree, and $\,\Bbb F_7 = \Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z\,$ is a field.