# Why can $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - d)-bc = 0$ be rewritten as $(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - d)-bc = 0$ which can also be written as $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+d) + (ad - bc) = 0$. This quadratic equation can be solved by finding the roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. With the roots, I have been told that $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+d) + (ad - bc) = 0$ can be written as $(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2) = 0$ - why?

Comment: You said $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - d)-bc = 0$ can be written as $\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+b) + (ad - bc) = 0$ but shouldn't it be $-\lambda(a+d)$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: Is your question related to chromatic numbers? Because you are used $\lambda$ as variable.

Comment: It's obvious, you could write an equation with two roots in two forms. So your question is not clear.

Answer (score 4):

If $x=\alpha$ is a root of a polynomial $p(x)$, you can always write $p(x)$ as
$$
p(x) = (x-\alpha)\cdot q(x),
$$
where $q(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $\deg(q)=\deg(p)-1$.

In your example $p(\lambda) = (\lambda - a)(\lambda - d)-bc$ is a polynomial of degree $2$. Since it has roots $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ you can write is as
$$
p(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)\cdot q(\lambda)
$$
where $q(\lambda)$ has degree $0$, that is, is a constant. However, since the coefficient of $\lambda^2$ in $p(\lambda)$ is $1$ we must have $q(\lambda)=1$ so that
$$
p(\lambda) = (\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Expanding $$(\lambda-a)(\lambda-d)-bc=0$$ we get
$$\lambda^2-a\lambda-d\lambda+ad-bc=0$$ this can be written as
$$\lambda-\lambda(a+d)+ad-bc=0$$
using the quadratic formula we obtain
$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{a+d}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}$$
now you can write
$$(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)=0$$
It is the same like above, called the theorem of Vieta.

Comment: What does this have to do with the roots $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Comment: I still do not understand why you can get from $$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{a+d}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4bc}$$
to
$$(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)=0$$

Comment: @FacPam See the [BiFactor Theorem.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) and the higher degree generalization of the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem) that I prove there.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Vieta's theorem:
$$\lambda^2 - \lambda(a+b) + (ad - bc) = 0 \Rightarrow \begin{cases}\lambda_1+\lambda_2=a+b\\ \lambda_1\lambda_2=ad-bc\end{cases}$$
and:
$$(\lambda - \lambda_1)(\lambda - \lambda_2) = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda^2-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)\lambda+\lambda_1\lambda_2=0$$
Do you see the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Have a close look at the polynomial $p_α(λ) = α(\lambda - λ_1)(\lambda - λ_2)$, $α\ne0$. Its roots are really obvious: $p_α(λ) = 0$ if and only if at least one of the factors $λ-λ_1$ and $λ-λ_2$ is zero. So this polynomials have the same roots as your polynomial $p(λ) = (\lambda - a)(\lambda - d)-bc$. The correct value of $α$ is the leading coefficient of $p(λ) = 1\cdotλ^2−λ(a+d)+(ad−bc)$, that is $α=1$.

When you really want to understand the mathematical background why this [factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization#Polynomials) works you need the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) but this may be beyond your skills.