# Is the set of roots unique for each $g(x)$ in $a_n x^n + g(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I woke up and suddenly wondered about the following: A polynomial of degree $n$ $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdot\cdot\cdot + a_{n-n} x^{n-n}$ can be written as $a_n x^n + g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. Then I was thinking that for every $g(x)$ has a unique set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicities - is this true?

So for instance consider a polynomial of degree $2$: $x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$ which can be written as $x^2 + g(x)$ where $h(x) = a_1 x + a_0$. Then *every* unique combination of $a_1$ and $a_0$ in $g(x)$ will give a unique set of roots in terms of values and multiplicities.

An example of this is $x^2 + 5x + 4$ (with $a_2 = 1$) - this polynomial has the roots $-4$ and $-1$, both with a multiplicity of $1$. Thus, for this $a_2$, only $g(x) = 5x + 4$ will give this set of roots. Only for a different $a_n$ a different $g(x)$ may yield this set of roots. I mean after all, any polynomial of degree $2$ can be written as $a_2(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$.

This is all something that I *think* could be true. So can any of you smart guys out there tell me if I am right and if so, might explain why this holds - that the set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicities are unique for each $g(x)$?

Comment: You are saying "I mean after all, any polynomial of degree $2$ can be written as $a_2(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$." If $r1,r2$ are roots you can write the function as $f(x)=(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$ NOT as $f(x)=a_2(x - r_1)(x - r_2)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the fundamental theorem of algebra every polynomial can be written as the product of linear factors. These give you exactly the zeros and their multiplicity. So yes, every **monic** polynomial has a unique set of roots with respect to their multiplicity.

i.e. if we let $g(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n-1$, by the fundamental theorem of algebra we can find a unique $c\in\mathbb{C}$ and unique $x_{1},...,x_{n-1}\in\mathbb{C}$ such that
$$g(x)=c(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})...(x-x_{n-1}).$$
Hence the set of roots of a polynomial is unique for said polynomial up to multiplication by a scalar.

Comment: But *monic* just means that the leading coefficient is 1 - so isn't this just one case for which the set of roots for $g(x)$ is unique for this leading coefficient $a_n$. Wouldn't the uniqueness also hold when the leading variable $a_n \neq 1$, like $2$?

Comment: Every polynomial has a unique set of roots with respect to multiplicity. Every set of roots has a unique monic polynomial.

Comment: So it is true that the set of roots with respect to their values and multiplicities are unique for each $g(x)$ in $a_n x^n + g(x)$? Not only for $1 x^n + g(x)$ (monic) but any $a_n x^n + g(x)$. It would be very nice if you could elaborate :)

Comment: I've expanded my answer. I am not sure what the value is of considering $a_{n}x^{n}+g(x)$. In you're question you are only concerned by the roots of $g(x)$ and for this it only matters that $g(x)$ is a polynomial.

Comment: @FacPam Take $g^\prime(x)=\frac{g(x)}{a_n}$ and you're back to your original $1x^n+g^\prime(x)$. This would work for any particular $a_n\neq0$.