# Understanding the factoring of a polynomial completely into linear factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials, field-theory

I have a tough time understanding on the factorization of polynomials completely i.e. factoring a polynomial, say $f(x)$ to linear factors such that $a(x-r_1)\cdots (x-r_d)$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a,r_1,...,r_d\in \mathbb{F}$/

If we are able to factor polynomial $f(x)$ (with $\text{deg}(f(x))=d$) completely over the field $\mathbb{F}$, does this imply that $f(x)$ has the total of $d$ roots in $\mathbb{F}$?

For the contrary, if the polynomial $f(x)$ has the total of $t$ roots in $\mathbb{F}$ where $t<d$, then can we conclude that $f(x)$ may not be factored completely over the field $\mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Yes: the number of roots of a polynomial (counting multiplicity) is, by definition, the number of linear factors of the factored version of the polynomial (counting multiplicity).

Comment: Beware that a polynomial can have more roots than its degree over non-domains, e.g. $\,x^2-1\,$ has four roots $\,\pm1,\pm3\,$ over $\Bbb Z_8 =$ integers $\!\bmod 8.\,$ Over a field (or domain) the roots correspond to linear factors - which are (cancellable) *primes*, so occur *uniquely* in factorizations, so we can't have ave nonunique factorizations like $\,(x-1)(x+1) = (x-3)(x+3)\,$ in the prior example over $\Bbb Z_8.\,$ See  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) for more.